# Is “I play soccer, but I’m not playing right now" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> I play soccer, but I’m not playing right now.

Does the sentence make sense?

Answer (score 2):

It can mean two things:

1. I play soccer regularly, but I am not actually engaged in playing right at this moment.
2. I know how to play soccer, and have played regularly in the past, but at this stage in my life I'm not on a team or otherwise playing regularly.